# How to make PostSharp's OnMethodBoundaryAspect OnEntry method Asynchronous

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, postsharp

I apologize if I missed something and this question doesn't make sense or the answer wasn't obvious to me when reading through the PostSharp documentation.

I have created a simple logging aspect that uses a custom logging service to put details about a WCF method call into a database. Once the logging aspect is called, it needs to continue on its own and not hold up the execution of the WCF method itself. I am curious if the OnEntry() method can be made asynchronous? The custom logging service uses asynchronous calls to put the logs into the database, but was hoping for more separation between the two.

Aspect:

```
[Serializable]
class LoggingAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // Perform the logging
    }
}
```

WCF Method:

```
[LoggingAspect]
public String DoSomething(int param1, int param2)
{
    // Do stuff?
}
```

**EDIT: Solution**
Thanks to the info below I was able to come up with a solution that works for me. I was able to test this by writing some timestamps to a file for DoSomething() and the OnEntry(). I added a Thread.Sleep(30000) followed by another writing of a timestamp to PerformLog(). My DoSomething() method was able to finish up before PerformLog() finished off writing to my logging service :)

Aspect:

```
[Serializable]
class LoggingAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // Write timestamp to file.
        Task.Run( () => PerformLog(args) );
    }

    private void PerformLog(MethodExecutiionArgs args)
    {
        // Thread.Sleep(30000);
        // Write timestamp to file.
        // Perform the logging
    } 
}
```

WCF Method:

```
[LoggingAspect]
public String DoSomething(int param1, int param2)
{
    // Write timestamp to file.
    // Do stuff?
}
```

Comment: The only real option I see is: put whatever you want to be done asnychronisely into a global/static ConcurrentQueue and implement a thread which consumes/handles the work from that Queue - basically handle this with a Producer/Consumer pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just start a Task for your logging logic and let the OnEntry method return?

Comment: Are you referring to adding a Task in the separate logging service that I mentioned? We do have that separate logging service set up to run asynchronously so when that part is called we can forget about it and move on. The issue within this OnEntry is that I have quite a bit of work going on to get the data ready to send to our logging service that I do not need to wait for. From what I understand of Tasks and the async modifier is that they require an await in order to receive a response, you cannot just completely fire and forget.

Comment: The OnEntry is always called synchronously from your own method, so this answer gives the most reasonable solution. Move your OnEntry logic to another method and start an asynchronous task for it (Task.Run(...)), then return from OnEntry. If you want to ensure the task has ended before returning from your WCF method, then you can await the task in the OnExit method (store it in the MethodExecutionArgs.MethodExecutionTag).

Comment: I had not come across that you were able to simply perform a Task.Run() without an await to catch the return. I believe you two have lead me to a solution :) Marking this as correct and editing my question with what I ended up with.